# AWS DynamoDB - How to achieve in 1 call: Add value to set, if set exists - or else instantiate set with value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a users table, there is an attribute called friends, which will be a set of the id's of all the user's friends.

Initially I tried instantiating the friends attribute to an empty set when the user is created, but I get an error that you can't have an empty attribute.

So the only solution I could find if someone has no friends yet is to read the attribute on the user, if it does not exist, SET the attribute to a [new] set with the friend they are adding. If it does exist, then just perform an update with an ADD, which adds the new friend to the set.

I don't want to have to make two calls to AWS for this.

*Is there a way to create the set if it doesn't exist, and if it does, add to it - all in just 1 call?*

Answer (score 26):

**For SET data type (from [DynamoDB API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValueUpdate.html)):**

> **ADD** - If the attribute does not already exist, then the attribute and its values are added to the item. If the attribute does exist,
> then the behavior of ADD depends on the data type of the attribute:
>
> If the existing data type is a set, and if the Value is also a set,
> then the Value is added to the existing set. (This is a set operation,
> not mathematical addition.) For example, if the attribute value was
> the set [1,2], and the ADD action specified [3], then the final
> attribute value would be [1,2,3]. An error occurs if an Add action is
> specified for a set attribute and the attribute type specified does
> not match the existing set type. Both sets must have the same
> primitive data type. For example, if the existing data type is a set
> of strings, the Value must also be a set of strings. The same holds
> true for number sets and binary sets.

**Example:-**

**First update:-**

The `country` attribute is not present in the table. The `updateItem` created the new attribute `country` with the values (IN, UK) provided.

```
var params = {
        TableName : "Movies",
        Key : {
            "yearkey" : 2014,
            "title" : "The Big New Movie 2"
        },
        UpdateExpression : "ADD country :countries",            
         ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':countries': docClient.createSet(["IN", "UK"])             
            },
        ReturnValues : "UPDATED_NEW"
    };
```

**Second update:-**

This time `updateItem` added the new value "US" and ignored the existing value "IN".

```
var params = {
        TableName : "Movies",
        Key : {
            "yearkey" : 2014,
            "title" : "The Big New Movie 2"
        },
        UpdateExpression : "ADD country :countries",            
         ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':countries': docClient.createSet(["IN", "US"])             
            },
        ReturnValues : "UPDATED_NEW"
    };
```

Comment: I tried to use a regular JavaScript set and that threw errors. The docClient.createSet call appears to be the only way to make sets.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of using `aws` command line.

```
aws dynamodb update-item --table-name users \
--key '{"userId": {"S": "my-user-id"}}' \ 
--update-expression "ADD friends :friends" \
--expression-attribute-values '{":friends": {"SS": ["friend1-id", "friend2-id"]}}'
```

- `SS` indicates a set of strings (no duplicate allowed).
- No need to use `SET` in `update-expression` for non-existing case; `ADD` will handle it.

See [aws docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD).